# ensure encoding in Java and Terminal

Tags: java, http, encoding, utf-8

I have a Java2EE Application runnning on a WildFly 10, I am using Terminator (Terminal) to monitor what's going on and Sublime Text 2 to open the log files.

Now I am sending XML through HTTP and for some reason the encoding is messed up (I am german, so äüöß are screwed up). It should be UTF-8 since everything I use is UTF-8 by default, plus I double-checked anyways, and yes, it's UTF-8, but still the encoding is messed up.

But now when I check log files, terminal output or whatever ... 
All I see are question marks instead of ä, ö, ü and ß

So does anyone have productive ideas that could help me?

Comment: Did you triple-check that you are specifying UTF-8 for *all* conversions, including when receiving the request, when parsing the request body, when producing the log file and the terminal output? Most JRE installations will not use UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command in jboss-cli.sh

```
/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default:write-attribut‌​e(name=default-encod‌​ing,value=UTF-8)
```

then

```
reload
```

In general - it is not clear, whether you have problems displaying national chars in OS (check locale, LANG environment variables et c) or doing some programming error.

Also, if you are URLDecoding XMLs, be sure to specify encoding.
For example:

```
URLDecoder.decode(xml, "UTF-8"))
```